# How to use Shareable interface in Java Card applets?

Tags: java, javacard

I wrote two simple applets named *App1* and *App2* for my java card as follow :

**App1 :**

```
public class App1 extends Applet {

    private App1() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new App1().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
    if(selectingApplet()){
        return;
    }
     //I want to call "ThisMethod()" of App2 here


    }

}
```

**App2 :**

```
public class App2 extends Applet {

    private App2() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new App2().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {

    }

    public void ThisMethod(){
        ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9001);
    }

}
```

As I indicate in the App1 program (As comments) I want to call `ThisMethod`method of App2 in the `Process` method of App1. As far as I know I must implement `Shareable` interface. But I am a little confused about it :

**Questions :**

1- Should I implement this method in both applets? Or I need to implement it in just App1 or App2?

2- If App1 and App2 are in a single package or in two separate packages, does it change anything?

3- Do I need `Shareable` interface to share an array? Or it is mandatory just for sharing methods?

Comment: Answer is partly wrong. Refering to the followup thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29387433/3382542

Comment: @PaulBastian I edited this answer, if you see it is correct, maybe you want to delete your comment. (I'll delete this comment later.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you only must create an interface that extends Shareable and then your app2 must implement that interface.
2. It doesn't matter.
3. Yes you also need to implement `Shareable` if you want to share your array

However, before you can use methods/objects shared from other applet instance, you must first store the instance of your interface in App1. You can do this by

```
AID aid = JCSystem.lookupAid({App2 AID byte array}, {offset}, {length});  // provide the instance AID of App2

{yourInterface} app2Instance = ({yourInterface})JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(aid, (byte)0);
```

then use `app2Instance` to access shared methods/objects

Comment: I follow above steps, but a new problem appears, I appreciate you if take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339911/why-applet-conversion-failed-in-case-of-using-shareable-interface-how-to-use-e

Comment: Sorry, I change the answer in a way that it worked for me. If you see something is wrong, please inform me.