# Why applet conversion failed in case of using Shareable interface? (How to use Export files in such cases)

Tags: javacard

I wrote two java card applet named *MasterApp* and *SlaveApp* that are in two different packages named *masterPack* and *slavePack* :

**Master AIDs :**

- Package : `01 02 03 04 01`
- Applet  : `01 02 03 04 01 01`

**Slave AIDs :**

- Package : `01 02 03 04 02`
- Applet  : `01 02 03 04 02 02`

As you see below I want to call `SharedMethod()` of the *MasterApp* in the `Process()` method of my *SlaveApp* :

**Master Program :**

```
package masterPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Shareable;
import javacard.framework.Util;
public class MasterApp extends Applet implements Shareable {
    // goodNews = "Shared Method Called Successful"
    byte[] goodNews = { (byte) 'S', (byte) 'h', (byte) 'a', (byte) 'r',
            (byte) 'e', (byte) 'd', (byte) ' ', (byte) 'M', (byte) 'e',
            (byte) 't', (byte) 'h', (byte) 'o', (byte) 'd', (byte) ' ',
            (byte) 'C', (byte) 'a', (byte) 'l', (byte) 'l', (byte) 'e',
            (byte) 'd', (byte) ' ', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'u', (byte) 'c',
            (byte) 'c', (byte) 'e', (byte) 's', (byte) 's', (byte) 'f',
            (byte) 'u', (byte) 'l' };

    private MasterApp() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new MasterApp().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

    }

    public void SharedMethod(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(goodNews, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
                (short) goodNews.length);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) goodNews.length);
    }

}
```

**Slave Program :**

```
package slavePack;

import masterPack.MasterApp;
import javacard.framework.AID;
import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;

public class SlaveApp extends Applet {

    byte[] masterAppletAID={(byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01};
    AID aid = JCSystem.lookupAID(masterAppletAID, (short)0, (byte)masterAppletAID.length);
    MasterApp MasterAppInstance = (MasterApp)JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(aid, (byte)0);

    private SlaveApp() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new SlaveApp().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        if(selectingApplet()){
            return;
        }
        MasterAppInstance.SharedMethod(apdu);

    }

}
```

In the first step I convert the *MasterApp* to *.cap* file successfully and now I have its *.exp* file in the same directory of its *.cap* file.

As the second step I wanted to convert *SlaveApp* to *.cap* file, but I failed. I guessed that I need to the previous *.exp* file in the directory of *SlaveApp* for conversion, so I move it to the directory of *SlaveApp.class* and tried again, but nothing changed and I received the same below errors again :

[image]

**Questions :**

1- What's the origin of the error?

2- How can I restrict this sharedMethod only for one applet? I mean, in this situation all the other applets can call it, is there any way to limit this accessibility?

3- In cases that we don't have the *.exp* file of *MasterApp*, what we must do?

Note that I appreciate any other comment to make my program more efficient (For example the type of variables and their declaration's points).

---

**Update :**

Based on @Paul-Bastin answer, I added an interface named `MyShareableInterface` to my the *MasterApp* package and this interface implements the `Shareable` interface. In this Interface I declared the same `SharedMethod` method that I used in MasterApp as interface. After that I implement this Interface using MasterApp applet. All the other are the same, but nothing changed.

**MyShareableInterface.java :**

```
package masterPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Shareable;

public interface MyShareableInterface extends Shareable {
    public void SharedMethod(APDU apdu);

}
```

**MasterApp.java :**

```
public class MasterApp extends Applet implements MyShareableInterface {
//Same Body
}
```

**SlaveApp.java :**

It is exactly the same as before.

**Problem :** Nothing changed. I had the same error.

---

**Update 2:**

`APDU` object removed from input arguments of `SharedMethod` in all three files. It's body replaced with `ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9100)` also (In the `MasterApp.java`). I have the same errors againg.

After the above changes I recreate the project from the beginning and now I am dealing with three `.java` file in two packages as follow :

**MyShareableInterface.java :**

```
package masterPack;

import javacard.framework.Shareable;

public interface MyShareableInterface extends Shareable{
    public void SharedMthod();
}
```

**MasterApp.java :**

```
package masterPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

public class MasterApp extends Applet implements MyShareableInterface {

    private MasterApp() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new MasterApp().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void SharedMthod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9100);

    }

}
```

**SlaveApp.java :**

```
package slavePack;

import masterPack.MasterApp;
import javacard.framework.AID;
import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;

public class SlaveApp extends Applet {

    byte[] masterAppletAID={(byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01};
    AID aid = JCSystem.lookupAID(masterAppletAID, (short)0, (byte)masterAppletAID.length);
    MasterApp MasterAppInstance = (MasterApp)JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(aid, (byte)0);

    private SlaveApp() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new SlaveApp().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        if(selectingApplet()){
            return;
        }
        MasterAppInstance.SharedMthod();

    }

}
```

There is no error in the code. I can even convert the `MasterApp.java` to *.cap* file successfully. There problem is failure in `SlaveApp.java` conversion procedure. I failed in this step.

Note that : AID-s are the same as first version of question. Two first file are in `masterPack` and the latter is in `slavePack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must create an interface that extends Shareable.
2. Then your applet must implement that interface
3. You get this interface in your slave applet yb calling `JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject`
4. You call the public method of your interface over this object
5. Do not share the apdu object!

I highly recommend Zhiqun Chen - Java Card Technology Book

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74350/discussion-on-answer-by-paul-bastian-why-applet-conversion-failed-in-case-of-usi).