# Java card returns 0x6F00 on the calling point of a shared method

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339911/why-applet-conversion-failed-in-case-of-using-shareable-interface-how-to-use-e) question's programs to test `Shareable` interface on my Java Card.

Just like the question I wrote an applet named Master with AID = `010203040101` and another one named Slave with AID =`010203040202`. These are the files:

**MyShareableInterface.java :**

```
package master;

import javacard.framework.Shareable;

public interface MyShareableInterface extends Shareable {
    public void ShareMethod();

}
```

**Master.java :**

```
package master;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

public class Master extends Applet implements MyShareableInterface {

    private Master() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new Master().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {

        if (selectingApplet()){
            ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9100);
        }
        ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9200);
    }

    public void ShareMethod() {
        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x6103);
    }

}
```

**Slave.java :**

```
package slave;

import master.MyShareableInterface;
import javacard.framework.AID;
import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;

public class Slave extends Applet {
    byte[] masterAppletAID={(byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01};
     AID aid = JCSystem.lookupAID(masterAppletAID, (short)0, (byte)masterAppletAID.length);
     MyShareableInterface MasterShareableInterfaceInstance = (MyShareableInterface)JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(aid, (byte)0);

     private Slave() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new Slave().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()){
            ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9400);
            return;
        }
        MasterShareableInterfaceInstance.ShareMethod();

    }

}
```

Finally I convert these two applets to *.cap* files and upload them on my card successfully. I expect the card to have the below behavior:

- Return **0x9100** on reception of Master applet selection
- Return **0x9200** on reception of any other commands while Master is selected
- Return **0x9400** on reception of Slave applet selection
- Return **0x6103** on reception of any other commands while Slave is selected

But this is what I receive in above conditions:

```
OpenSC: OSC -s 00a4040006010203040101 -s 00000000 -s 00a4040006010203040202 -s 00000
000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 01 01
Received (SW1=0x91, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x92, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 02 02
Received (SW1=0x94, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x6F, SW2=0x00)
```

As you see above, the first three commands return the correct response, but the latter (calling `SharedMethod`) throws an `0x6F00` exception. Why?

Note that I tested the above *.cap* files with two different JavaCards (2.2.1 and 3.0.1) and both act similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive the status word 0x6F00 because you get an unhandled null pointer exception at

```
MasterShareableInterfaceInstance.ShareMethod();
```

The reason for this null pointer exception is that `MasterShareableInterfaceInstance` is null.

You try to get an instance of the sharable interface through

```
(MyShareableInterface)JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(aid, (byte)0);
```

upon instantiating your applet object. Your approach does not work for multiple reasons. You have to make sure the following:

- the slave applet must already be registered when you invoke `getAppletShareableInterfaceObject`. You currently invoke this method in your applet constructor and hence call it *before* you call `Applet.register()`. So you have to make sure to use `getAppletShareableInterfaceObject` only after you called the `register()` method. So it may be a good idea to call this method directly from your `process()` method.
- the master applet is already registered when you call `getAppletShareableInterfaceObject`
- the master applet has to override the `getShareableInterfaceObject` method and return the shareable interface object (the default implementation will return null):

  ```
  public Shareable getShareableInterfaceObject(AID clientAID, byte parameter)
  ```

  This method allows the master applet to decide if it will allow the client applet to use the shareable interface. As your master applet does not implement this method, sharing is denied by default.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure that I understand correctly : **1 :** _the master applet is already registered when you call getAppletShareableInterfaceObject_ This is not my problem, because my client installed successfully. in cases of this problem, we can't install the applet, right?  **2 :** They wrote this method in a way that it returns null by default to force the programmer override it, because they want the programmer to specify clearly which applet have accessibility to  shareable interface and which applet don't.right? (Is there any other reason?)

Comment: **3 :** What shall I write in the body of this override method?

Comment: (1) You client applet should install fine, even if the master applet is not available (note that you do not perform any checks to see if `aid` or `MasterShareableInterfaceInstance` are null when you register your client applet.

Comment: But in cases that I want to install the Slave before the Master, the installation  have failure. I mean I must install the Master first. why?

Comment: Dear Michael, I added the following method to the Master program and  I still receive the same error : `public Shareable getShareableInterfaceObject(AID clientAID, byte parameter){
  return this;
  
 }` Am I wrong in something?

Comment: (1) I follow vojta's suggestion (I tried to throw `0x9100` or `0x6103` in `ShareMehtod()`, both failed with `0x6F00` in response).    (2) Yes I install master first. (I can't install slave first! It returns `0x6A80` [Incorrect parameters in command data field] when I want to install slave first). (3) hard reset between installations didn't help me. (4) I tried two different card but I have the same error.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you try to instantiate the shared interface during command execution (instead of during installation time) by executing the `JCSystem.lookupAID()` and the `JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject()` within the `process()` method. Also make sure to check each return value for `null` and return different status codes to track down the error.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine now! I move these two methods (`JCSystem.lookupAID()` and  `JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject()` ) to `process` method's body and now it works fine! but why?

Comment: Note these methods wasn't in `install` method's body before! they was in the scope of `Slave` class. Should I use them in `install` method?

Comment: BTW, I define `aid` and `MasterAppInstance` as static fields and move `JCSystem.lookupAID()` and `JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject()` to the `install` method. In this case I receive the same first error (`0x6F00`). So the only correct form is using this methods in my `process` method. But why this is the only one correct form?

Comment: Sure you *did* have those in your install method: In your install method, you call `new Slave()`, which invokes the constructor of class Slave which in turn instantiates those objects.

Comment: So what is the problem? What it works fine only when I call those methods in `process` method and not in other forms?

Comment: Looking at your code again, it is quite obvious why it did not work before: You called `getAppletShareableInterfaceObject()` from your applet's constructor which is invoked *before* `Applet.register()` is called. However, `getAppletShareableInterfaceObject()` will only work *after* the `register()` method was called.

Comment: So the efficient way is define `aid` and `MasterShareableInterfaceInstance` as _static_ fields and  adding these method calls after the line `new Slave().register();` in the `install` method? or calling these methods in `if(selectingApplet()){}` scope? Which one is better?

Comment: May I ask you to edit your answer to cover this issues also? Thanks

Comment: You better don't store such values in static fields for security reasons (I'm not sure that storing them in static fields is even possible).

Comment: So the only option in calling them in `process` method repeatedly each time I need them?

Answer (score 2):

Change status word `0x6103` to any other status word from the interval dedicated by ISO7816 (or ETSI if you write an applet for SIM card). Try using `0x9003` instead, for example.

http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_iso7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx

SW1 = 0x61 means there are still some response bytes available. SW2 indicates the number of these bytes. Some readers (and libraries) handle this status word by themselves and that can cause your troubles (you say there are 3 bytes available, although there is not a single one).

Comment: Thanks. I tried it already with different Status words, and now I tried 0x9003 instead of 0x6103 also, but nothing changed. I have the same error again( 0x6f00)